# How can i improve performance of My model without Normalization?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm, data-science, feature-extraction

I'm new to Python and data science. I'm working on Electricity Load Forecasting. When I use Normalisation the results are Good. I get very Small MAE and MSE. But when I apply SVR on the same data without Normalisation I get very High MSE and MAE value.

```
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_error 
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import pandas as pd
from sklearn import preprocessing
features=pd.read_csv('selectedData.csv')

names=list(features)
for i in names:
```

Normalising my Data here

```
 x=features[[i]].values.astype(float)
 min_max_scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
x_scaled = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(x)
features[i]=x_scaled

#Selecting the target Variable which want to predict and for which we are 
finding feature imps 
target = features['SYSLoad']
features= features.drop('SYSLoad', axis = 1)
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
train_input, test_input, train_target, test_target = 
train_test_split(features, target, test_size = 0.25, random_state = 42)

n=test_target.values;
test_targ=pd.DataFrame(n);


 #train the model using the training sets 
from sklearn.svm import SVR
svr_rbf = SVR(kernel='rbf', C=10, epsilon=0.01,gamma=1)
y_rbf = svr_rbf.fit(train_input, train_target);
predicted=y_rbf.predict(test_input);

plt.xlim(20,100);
print('Total Days For training',len(train_input)); print('Total Days For 
Testing',len(test_input))
plt.ylabel('Load(MW) Prediction 3 '); plt.xlabel('Days'); 
plt.plot(test_targ,'-b',label='Actual'); plt.plot(predicted,'-r',label='RBF 
kernel ');
plt.gca().legend(('Actual','RBF'))
plt.title('SVM')
plt.show();

mae=mean_absolute_error(test_target,predicted)
mse=mean_squared_error(test_target, predicted)
print("MAE By RBF :",  mae);
print("MSE By RBF :", mse);
```

> Should I Use Feature Extraction?  I Have obtained SVR Parameters from Grid search?

```
epsilon=[0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1]
C = [0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10]
gammas = [0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1]
param_grid = {'C': C, 'gamma' : gammas, 'epsilon':epsilon}
grid_search = GridSearchCV(SVR(kernel='RBF'), param_grid, cv=3);
grid_search.fit(train_input, train_target);
print(grid_search.best_params_);
```

[image: OutPut]

Comment: Why do you not want to normalise the features?  It's standard practice to do so for an SVM, as otherwise features on larger scales will dominate the model.

Comment: @Chris  with normalization prediction takes very less time. But when I predict with the model the result are also in Normalised formed which i need to be in Denormalised form Is there a way to do it ?

Comment: Ah, yes I see what you've done.  The simplest thing to do is move `target = features['SYSLoad']` and `features= features.drop('SYSLoad', axis = 1)` to before the `for` loop where you normalise the data – only the independent variables need to be scaled.

Comment: Technically, you should also `min_max_scaler.fit_transform` the `train` data and then `min_max_scaler.transform` the `test` data.  Remember the `test` data is a way of pretending we have out of sample (unknown) data to verify the model, so we should also pretend we can't fit the scaler to it.

Comment: @Chris So I should Normalise only dependent data Which is test_input and Train_input in my case?

Comment: Yeah, exactly.  And only fit the normaliser to `train_input` – then use that fitted normaliser to transform `test_input`.  There are cases where you may want to pre-process the target variable, e.g. so that the MSE/RMSE for a regressor can be used to fit across a target over several orders of magnitude.  In that case you could take the log of the target variable and then take the exponent of the predictions to obtain the 'untransformed' values.  I'd try your model with the original target variable first and then look at preprocessing the target if you need to improve the test accuracy.

Comment: @Chris Does Perfomance of SVR is affected by feature extraction (Dimensionality reduction )

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185554/discussion-between-chris-and-imtiaz-ul-hassan).